# How to filter column with values without NULL or blanks using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to filter out the rows with values only, I have tried using several methods but it doesn't works. Processing the values further i need to have the dataframe without values without having any Null or blank rows.

Input Data:

```
Col 1
U_a65839_Jan87Apr88
U_b98652_Feb88Apr88
NaN
Q_d15634_Apr90Apr91
S_e15336_may91Apr93
NaN
```

Expected Output:

Input Data:

```
Col 1
U_a65839_Jan87Apr88
U_b98652_Feb88Apr88
Q_d15634_Apr90Apr91
S_e15336_may91Apr93
```

**Code i have been using :**

```
df['Col 1'] = df[~df['Col 1'].isnull()]
```

**ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 60, placement implies 1**

Comment: Just `df = df[~df['Col 1'].isnull()]`. Also `df = df[df['Col1'].notnull()]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang - Having the same error ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 60, placement implies 1

Comment: Please see again, there is no `['Col 1']` on the left hand side...

Comment: @QuangHoang -  I need to put as for further processing i cant assign into the whole dataframe. As i need to assign to df['Col 1'] column only , Is there any way to work around.

Comment: what do you need to *put as for further processing*? You cannot stuff a dataframe `df[~df['Col 1'].isnull()]` to a column `df['Col 1']`. You can use another variable: `df1 = df[~df['Col 1'].isnull()]` and use that.